# Why am I getting "The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. " error when exporting dataframe to CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a mini quiz application in Python / Pandas.

The user calls a next() function, causing a new question to be retrieved at random from a Pandas data frame (read from a csv file)
Various other things happen as well based on whether the user gets the question right or not.

However, my final line `df.to_csv` seems to be causing a `"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. " error`

This is odd, as the statement is not trying to be a Boolean. What is prompting the error then?

===**Code**===

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def next():
    df = pd.read_csv('qs.csv')
    hi = df[df['priority']=='hi'].copy()
    number = random.randint(0,len(hi)-1)
    name = hi.loc[number,'name']
    answer = hi.loc[number,'answer']
    question = hi.loc[number,'question']
    a = input(question)
    if a == answer:
        if (df.loc[df['name']==name,'run'][0] + 1) in [5]:
                df.loc[df['name']==name,'priority'] = 'lo'
        else:
            df.loc[df['name']==name,'run'] = df.loc[df['name']==name,'run'].values[0] + 1

    elif a in ['q']:
        return

    else:
        print('incorrect')
        df.loc[df['name']==name,'run'] = 0
        
    df.to_csv('qs.csv')
```

This is the full error:

```
>>> next()
Where is the Tate Gallery located?London
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/willcharles/Documents/Quiz/quiz.py", line 30, in next
    **df.to_csv('qs.csv')**
  File "/Users/willcharles/Documents/Quiz/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1330, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: That error message doesn't come from the code you posted (which doesn't even have a line 30.)

Comment: You *must* provide a [mcve]